# Get current CategoryModel filled with data from Nop to my plugin

Tags: plugins, nopcommerce

Could you please help me on the following?

I am developing a plugin in nop commerce and I need to get the current CategoryModel from nop.web. How I can get it filled with the appropriate data into my plugin? 
I tried using the

```
EngineContext.Current.Resolve<CategoryModel>();
```

but it fails.Hope it is clear.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CategoryModel` class is a data entity, and is not intended to be injected or retrieved from the service locator.

It is not clear what you're trying to do, or if you're working in the administration backend or the public frontend (they both have different implementations of the `CategoryModel`) but the most likeable starting point is to get an instance of the category service.

```
EngineContext.Current.Resolve<ICategoryService>();
```

and go on from there...

Or, depending on your implementation, it would be much better to use DI at your class constructor to get the category service.

Comment: Hi, I need the CategoryModel filled with the data in the public front end. Should I create this model and fill it with data from beginning in the plugin's controller or is there any quick way to take it from engine's context? As far as I can understand, what I am trying to may be similar to what is done in Nop.Plugin.Misc.FacebookShop.

Comment: You need to populate the model yourself. You can follow the example you provide. The Facebook plugin has it's own category model and if fills it itself, check `PrepareCategorySimpleModels`. Those models are ad hoc classes specifically designed for the task they perform and filled at the controllers.

Comment: Actually, I need to get the SpecificationFilterModel and PriceRangeFilterItem based on the storeid and category id in order to implement my own filters. How this can be done?

Comment: Actually, that's a different question, but I guess the same principles apply.

Comment: Thanks for your help Mr. Regueira, it seems that I am on the right way. I took some code from \Presentation\Nop.Web\Controllers\CatalogController.cs and populated the filters. I think that I am on it. Please keep any eye in case anything will emerge. Thanks again.

Comment: If you found the answer helpful you should consider marking it as the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Hi again, thanks for reminding this. How could I impement the option in public front end to show the plugin on manufacturer or vendor pages?

Comment: I think I found it. I need to check if Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString() == "ManufacturerNavigation"